# Difference between Apache process and WSGIDaemon process?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a Django application running with Apache prefork (my code is not thread safe).
I am relatively new to Apache, so apologies in advance if this is too basic.

As far as I understand the main differences are:

- **Apache process**: control access and serve static files
- **WSGI process**: execute python code

Does this mean that if I define `MaxRequestWorkers` in Apache as 250, and wsgi `processes = 10`... then each one of the 250 Apache processes can start another 10 wsgi processes to run python?

Also, according to [mod_wsgi documentation](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/user-guides/processes-and-threading.html#) sites using Apache prefork should set the wsgi `threads = 1`
My site actually works when setting wsgi `threads = 5` with Apache prefork. But doesn't work with Apache worker since the code is not thread safe... How can this be?